# C# efficient reading of stream content with a limit on amount read

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

I have a case where a web API call returns a very large response of string.  I make the call as follows:

```
var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(blobStream.CopyToBytes()), 
                         "upload", Path.GetFileName(fileName));

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/v1/textResponse", multipartContent);
int responeLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.HasValue ? 
                    (int)response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value : -1;

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

I only need to process the first 1Mb of data from the response, so if the response is less than 1Mb I will read all but if it's more I will hard stop my read at 1Mb.

I am looking for the most efficient way to do this read.  I've tried this code:

```
// section above...

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string contentText = null;

if (responeLength < maxAllowedLimit) // 1Mb
{
     // less then limit - read all as string.
     contentText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
} 
else {
     var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[5120]; // read in chunks of 5KB
         int bytesRead;
         while((bytesRead = contentStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
         {
             stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
         contentText = stream.ConvertToString();
     }
}
```

Is this the most efficient way and how can I limit the amount read (the else).  I've tried this code and it always returns an empty string.  There is also:

```
ReadAsStringAsync()
ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
ReadAsStreamAsync()
LoadIntoBufferAsync(int size)
```

Are any of these methods more efficient?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Not sure how your `ConvertToString` method is implemented, but you probably need to set the `Position` of your MemoryStream back to 0 first

Comment: Also, look at `Stream.CopyTo` - no need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Note that you can't just take a stream of UTF-8 bytes, and hard stop after a certain number of bytes. You might well end up in the middle of a codepoint, and that will produce an invalid string. You can either use a StreamReader, or call `Encoding.GetDecoder()`

Comment: I tired this @canton7 - ```
                    var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentStream, 0, _settings.TextSizeUpperLimitBytes);```  was this what you meant?  Seems to work well!  Is this a more efficient way to grab a portion of the stream?

Comment: @RobMcCabe I didn't suggest doing that in any way, shape or form. I said you will have to use `StreamReader`, or `Encoding.GetEncoder()`. The first works on streams. The second works on byte arrays, but you can feed it bytes bit-by-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the most efficient (but still correct) way of doing this is probably something like this. This is made more complex by the fact that you have a limit on the number of *bytes* that are read, not the number of *characters*, and so we can't use a `StreamReader`. Note that we have to be careful not to stop reading in the middle of a codepoint - there are many cases where a single character is represented using multiple bytes, and stopping midway through would be an error.

```
const int bufferSize = 1024;
var bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
var chars = new char[Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize)];
var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
// We don't know how long the result will be in chars, but one byte per char is a
// reasonable first approximation. This will expand as necessary.
var result = new StringBuilder(maxAllowedLimit);
int totalReadBytes = 0;
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    while (totalReadBytes <= maxAllowedLimit)
    {
        int readBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(
            bytes,
            0,
            Math.Min(maxAllowedLimit - totalReadBytes, bytes.Length));

        // We reached the end of the stream
        if (readBytes == 0)
            break;

        totalReadBytes += readBytes;

        int readChars = decoder.GetChars(bytes, 0, readBytes, chars, 0);
        result.Append(chars, 0, readChars);
    }
}
```

Note that you'll probably want to use [`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption), otherwise `HttpClient` will go and download the whole body anyway.

If you're happy limiting by the number of *characters*, then life is easier:

```
string result;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
    char[] chars = new char[maxAllowedLimit];
    int read = reader.ReadBlock(chars, 0, chars.Length);
    result = new string(chars, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: This led me to my solution - hopefully this is efficient:  

                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[responeLength];
                    stream.Read(dataBytes, 0, responeLength);

                    text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);            
                }

Comment: @RobMcCabe As I've tried to explain many times, that is not safe if you have any characters which aren't ascii! This is because any non ascii characters are represented as multiple bytes in utf-8, and if you stop taking bytes half way through a character, you'll end up with an invalid string! Also you don't see how many bytes were read from the stream, and if the whole body hadn't been read yet you won't fill your bytes array! There's a reason my answer is a bit complex - you can't simply remove that complexity and still expect it to work!

Comment: @RobMcCabe Please try and understand this. I didn't put together my answer so that you could ignore everything I've tried to explain. Please read what I've written, and understand why my answer says to do the things it does.

Comment: Ok I get your meaning now canton7 - makes sense and actually my scenario may have other character sets such as ascii!  So good point!  I will use your sample above!  Thanks